# Trouble upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 13 9380

Tags: upgrade, dell, 22.04, xps

My Dell XPS 13 9380 shipped with Ubuntu 18.04.

I upgraded it to 20.04 about a year ago and everything worked perfectly.

With the recent point release of Ubuntu 22.04, the Software Updater provided the option to upgrade. I ran the upgrade all fine and then did a restart.

On reboot it is just stuck on the Dell logo black screen. If I hold down the power button to force shutdown and then restart, I am presented with the following options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- UEFI firmware settings
- Restore OS to factory settings

If I select the first option - Ubuntu - it says

```
error: out of memory
Press any key to continue
```

When I press any key I just get stuck on the Dell logo again.

If I select Advanced options for Ubuntu, and selected the latest kernel (recovery mode), it dumps a bunch of text to the screen, with the final line saying

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

and then it is just stuck on this screen.

Any ideas of how to fix this? Or does this just mean my machine can't run 22.04?

**Update 24/10/2022:**
I have been running Ubuntu 22.04 on this machine for a few months without any issues after installing from a USB. However, this issue/question is still valid as I am/was unable to upgrade from 20.04 - I had to do a clean install.

Comment: If the upgrade failed, attempt a new install. There should be no problem installing Ubuntu 22.04 on that machine.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work if I do a clean install from USB. But it is still a bug that I can't upgrade...